# Does Google Form on AMP require HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, embed, amp-html, google-forms

I am trying to embed a Google Form on my AMP page but when I try to use the AMP code. It just says "Loading..." where the Google Form suppose to be:http://mogotest.com/amp/purple-mattress-coupon.html (see on mobile)

Steps I took so far.
1. I put this code in the header of the AMP page

```
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe"
  src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```

2. I put this Google Form code on the page.

```
<amp-iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeFJf7DVgmzPEE1UfYXE3Oy0aBef80QXmRtLfKd1-b8aek0IQ/viewform?embedded=true" width=“100%” height="678" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</amp-iframe>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or is the issue that my AMP page is not HTTPS?

Comment: HTTPS and CORS are prerequisites

Comment: so it it required to have https to have a google form working?

Comment: ibid previous comment

Comment: @JayGray HTTPS is not required, its required for some features like video, iframes, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your site to HTTPS in order to work with **video, iframes**.

In below article it is clearly mentioned what will work with http and what will not work without https.

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/create/basic_markup/?format=websites

Comment: ibid previous comment. the OP does not seem to accept the advice.